# Swift 4 - NSURLComponents setting password with forward slash in it

Tags: ios, swift

I am using NSURLComponents and I am setting a username and password:

```
let urlComponents = NSURLComponents(string: webservice);
urlComponents?.user = username;
urlComponents?.password = password;
```

The password I am using has a special character in it (forward slash / )

I have confirmed that the password being entered is correct and all other passwords I am attempting work, except the one with this / in it.

Do I have to escape the special character?

Here is the full method:

```
func loginUser(_ username: String, password: String, completion: @escaping (_ result: Bool) -> Void)
    {

        let urlComponents = NSURLComponents(string: webservice);
        urlComponents?.user = username;
        urlComponents?.password = password

        let url = urlComponents?.url;

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: {
            (data, response, error) in

            if(error != nil){

                completion(false)

            }else{

                do{

                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options:.allowFragments) as! [String : AnyObject]


                    OperationQueue.main.addOperation({

                        self.appDelegate.communityArray = json

                        //Get Community Descrtiptions and add them to appDelegates communityDescriptionArray


                        self.getCommunities() { (result: Dictionary<String, Dictionary<String, Any>>) in

                            self.appDelegate.communityList = result

                            completion(true)

                        }

                    })

                }catch let error as NSError{

                    print(error)
                    completion(false)

                }
            }

        }).resume()

    }
```

I get the error when i try

```
let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options:.allowFragments) as! [String : AnyObject]
```

The error I get it:

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around
>   character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around
>   character 0.}

Comment: Check `print(urlComponents!.string!)` – the forward slash should be escaped automatically. The problem might be somewhere else.

Comment: @Rob: `var urlc = URLComponents(string: "http://myhost.com")!; urlc.user = "user"; urlc.password = "pass/word" ; print(urlc.string!)` prints `http://user:pass%2Fword@myhost.com`

Comment: I did print(urlComponents!.string!) and it does in fact has %2F instead of /

Comment: @MartinR - Quite right. My bad. I was thinking about key/value pairs in the URL, not the the `user`/`password` values.

Comment: So apparently the server sends something back which is not JSON – perhaps an error message? Print `String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)` to see the server response.

Comment: When I do that, it returns an entire HTML code but the summary of that is inside the body tag is this: 401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.

Comment: Is there away I can revert the %2F back to / in the url?

Comment: I've tried to create a URL like so let newURL = URL(string: "https://" + username + "@" + password + ":example.com" but that did not work for any password :(

Comment: correction: let newURL = URL(string: "https://" + username + ":" + password + "@example.com") still did not work

Answer (score 0):

You should never pass a password as part of the URL. The URL is sent in cleartext to upstream DNS servers.

Also, it's not clear what you're trying to do. The "@" sign and the "/" character are not legal characters in URLs. Well, the "/" is legal, but it's a path separator.

Answer (score 0):

The forward slash character MUST be percent-encoded to "%2F" in the authority component (the user and password are fields in the userinfo subcomponent of the authority) because it is a reserved character, a general delimiter, in URI/URL strings. If the forward slash were not percent-encoded, then it would mark the end of the authority component and be the first character of the path component.

Also (as noted in Michael Shulman's answer), RFC3986 says the use of the format "user:password" in the userinfo subcomponent of a URL is deprecated -- that's because passing authentication information in clear text has proven to be a security risk.